# Consecutive Proximal Projections as a Solution to Sum of Many Functions Each with Known Proximal Operator

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone, subgradient, proximal-operators, nuclear-norm

I have a sparse matrix factorization problem, where I want to decompose a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ to $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and   $B\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$, such that $X\approx AB$.

My matrix $X$ might have outlier values and missing values (that are replaced by zero). While I am aware of robust PCA, and low-rank plus sparse decomposition (E.g. in Candès et. al 2009-2016), I do not want to address the outliers directly.

I want to solve the following optimization program instead:

$$\text{minimize}_{A,B\geq 0} ~~\beta\|X-AB\|_F^2+(1-\beta)\|X-AB\|_1+\gamma_1\|A\|_1+\gamma_2\|B\|_1+\lambda\|A\|_*$$

$\|A\|_*$ is the nuclear norm of $A$, and it tries to encourage $A$ to be low-rank. Since this program is not jointly convex in $A$ and $B$, I want to solve it by alternating between the two, so let's assume I just want to solve it for $A$:

$$\text{minimize}_{A\geq 0} ~~\beta\|X-AB\|_F^2+(1-\beta)\|X-AB\|_1+\gamma_1\|A\|_1+\lambda\|A\|_*$$

I have the following questions:

1. Can I use a sequence of proximal projections for iteratively solving this problem? If yes, what should be the sequence of applying the projections?
2. If not, what is the best approach? I have tried subgradient descent, and it is not giving me a satisfactory convergence rate.
3. I would like to avoid off-the-shelf solvers, but if there is too much hassle to implement this myself (e.g. in Python's Scipy), are there any **free** solvers out there that scale to $n\approx10^9$ and $m\approx 10^4$?

Thanks!

Comment: By $\| A \|_{1}$, do you mean the matrix one norm or the sum of the absolute values of the entries of $A$?

Comment: I mean the sum of absolute values of the entries in the matrix.

Comment: Related to [Composition of Proximal Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following, so I thought maybe I should post it here too.

We can also formulate this problem as a cone program, some thing like:

$\text{minimize}_{A\geq 0} ~~\beta\|X-AB\|_F^2+(1-\beta)t_1+\gamma_1 t_2+\lambda \|A\|_*$

$\text{subject to}$

$\quad\|X-AB\|_1\leq t_1$

$\quad\|A\|_1\leq t_2$

Since we know that the consraints $\|X-AB\|_1\leq t_1$ and $\|A\|_1\leq t_2$ can be replaced by affine inequalities, and since we have  the following property. We can solve the problem using the interior point method.
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \|X\|_* \\
\text{subject to} & \mathcal{A}(X)=b \end{array}
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \tfrac{1}{2}\left( \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}W_1 + \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}W_2 \right) \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} W_1 & X \\ X^T & W_2 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\ & \mathcal{A}(X)=b \end{array}
$$

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

- The term "$\beta\|X-AB\|_{\text{F}}^2 + (1-\beta)\|X-AB\|_1$" really looks like bad modelling. What are you trying to capture with it ? Aren't you better off with just the term $\|X-AB\|_{\text{F}}^2$ ?
- Sequence of proximal operators applied anyhow will certainly diverge
- Subgradient descent has very bad complexity: $\mathcal O(1/\epsilon^2)$. You don't want to be doing this since this will only be a subproblem to solve at every step...
- There are proximal forward-backward algorithms which can deal with multiple *proximable* functions. For example there is the [Vu-Condat algorithm](https://www.gipsa-lab.grenoble-inp.fr/~laurent.condat/publis/Condat-optim-JOTA-2013.pdf) (see section 5).
- Finally, your original problem though nonconvex nonsmooth, it's *semi-algebraic* and can be attacked directly using recent works from Jerome Bolte, Heddy Attouch, and Marc Teboulle. For example, see page 12 of [these slides](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~teboulle/lx/lec7-to-8.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. "The term "$\beta\|X-AB\|_{\text{F}}^2 + (1-\beta)\|X-AB\|_1$" really looks like bad ..." Matrix $X$ is expected to be low-rank in general but we expect some large outlier values, I'll probably end up using a very small $\beta$. The ideal cost function would be a convex m-estimator loss like Huber, although I thought $L_1$ could be a good start.