# Proximal Operator of Summation of $ {L}_{1} $ Norm and $ {L}_{2, 1} $ Norm

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I would like the proximal operator of the following function:
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= \lambda_1 \|x\|_1 + \lambda_2 \|x\|_{2,1} \\
       &= \lambda_1 \|x\|_1 + \lambda_2 \sum_g \|x_g\|_2
\end{align}
where $x$ is the concatenation of all $x_g$, $\|x\|_1=\sum_i|x_i|$, and $\|y\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_i y_i^2}$.

I appreciate any help that is offered.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307741.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565332.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of the more general class of *summative* proximable functions, i.e. functions of the form

$$
x \mapsto f(x) + g(x)
$$
which satisfy $\mathrm{prox}_{f + g}(x) = \mathrm{prox}_{f} \left( \mathrm{prox}_g(x)
\right)$. See Appendix D of [A Primer on Coordinate Descent Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00040)
for more details and a proof.

For your specific instance, notice that since $\| x \|_1 = \sum_{g \in G} \| x_g \|_1$ from your definition of $x$, you can decompose your proximity operator into
$G$ separate instances of the form

$$
f_g(x) = \lambda_1 \| x_g \|_1 + \lambda_2 \| x_g \|_2.
$$

Each of these is then solvable using the rule for summative functions, i.e.

$$
\mathrm{prox}_{f_g}(x) = \mathrm{prox}_{\lambda_1 \| \cdot \|_1} \big(
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda_2 \| \cdot \|_2}(x) \big).
$$

Both of these proximal operators are known in closed form.
See Chapter 6 in [First Order Methods in Optimization](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611974997).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Pay attention @NicNic8 asked for the case of $ {L}_{1, 2} $. Your argument still holds yet it is not as the $ {L}_{2} $ you show.